# Could not find endpoint element

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

```
    <services>
  <service name="Lobby server.User Service" behavior Configuration="Service Behavior User">
    <host>
      <base Addresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5061" />
      </base Addresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="user" binding="netTcpBinding" binding Configuration="User Binding" contract="Lobby server.IUserService" />
    <endpoint address="user/Mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="ServiceBehaviorUser" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

  <service name="Lobby server.Public Service" behavior Configuration="ServiceBehaviorPublic">
    <host>
      <base Addresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5049" />
      </base Addresses>
    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="public" binding="netTcpBinding" binding Configuration="Public Binding" contract="Lobby server.IPublicService" />
    <endpoint address="public/Mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="ServiceBehaviorPublic" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>

</services>
<behaviors>
  <service Behaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviorUser">
      <service Debug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <service Metadata />
      <service Credentials useIdentityConfiguration="true">
        <service Certificate find Value="pident.cloudapp.net" store Location="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </service Credentials>
      <service Authorization principalPermissionMode="Always" />
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviorPublic">
      <service Debug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <service Metadata />
      <service Credentials>
        <service Certificate find Value="pident.cloudapp.net" store Location="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </service Credentials>
    </behavior>

  </service Behaviors>
</behaviors>
```

[image: Error]

I check the contract and name but then also error occur and address is null.

Error:

> Could not find endpoint element with name NetTcpBinding_IUserService
>   and contract Lobby server.IUserService in the Service Model client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this name could be found in the client element.

Any idea what is going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no endpoint with name: NetTcpBinding_IUserService

Try giving a name to the endpoint you want to use. Creating a channelFactory required the name of your endpoint indtead the name of your service.

Replace your nettcp endpoint with this one

```
<endpoint address="user" binding="netTcpBinding" binding Configuration="User Binding" 
 contract="Lobby server.IUserService" name="endpoint_NetTcp_IUserService"/>
```

And reference in your code like this:

```
new DuplexChannelFactory<IUserService>(new UserHandler(), "endpoint_NetTcp_IUserService");
```

Comment: i write 

 <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IUserService">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="IssuedToken"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

Comment: The name of the binding is how you reference it to your endpoint. You can set up an endpoint to use a particular binding. Then you have to set a name for your endpoint. This is used in your code.

Comment: See it like this. Factory-Endpoint linked by name.  Endpoint-binding linked by name

Comment: i also add service in that also endpoint is used, but still error occur

Comment: check my updated reply how to use. If you still have an error could it be it is a different one? please include if so

Comment: now i got address but 
now i got error in that line "UserServiceProxy = UserChannelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(user Token);" 
and error is "The InstanceContext provided to the ChannelFactory contains a UserObject that does not implement the CallbackContractType 'Lobbyserver.IUserClient'"

Comment: This means your "UserHandler" does not correctly implement your callback behaviour

Comment: Do you have resharper? Let it create the callback for you. If not hard to give a solution without the application code.